# PHP DOMDocument how to get element?

Tags: php, html, parsing, curl, domdocument

I am trying to read a website's content but i have a problem i want to get images, links these elements but i want to get elements them selves not the element content for instance i want to get that:  i want to get that entire element.

How can i do this..

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.link.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($output);

    $items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br />";
    }

    curl_close($ch);;
?>
```

Comment: Not to stray from your question but I suggest using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. It makes coding like this much simpler. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: I know about it and it would make my life easier but i think part of the code could be selled and i dont know if i can ship the libary with it.

Comment: I need to know how to get an entire element

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be asking for the *serialized html* of a DOMElement? E.g. you want a string containing `<a href="http://example.org">link text</a>`? (Please make your question clearer.)

```php
$url = 'http://example.com';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    // Best solution, but only works with PHP >= 5.3.6
    $htmlstring = $dom->saveHTML($a);

    // Otherwise you need to serialize to XML and then fix the self-closing elements
    $htmlstring = saveHTMLFragment($a);
    echo $htmlstring, "\n";
}


function saveHTMLFragment(DOMElement $e) {
    $selfclosingelements = array('></area>', '></base>', '></basefont>',
        '></br>', '></col>', '></frame>', '></hr>', '></img>', '></input>',
        '></isindex>', '></link>', '></meta>', '></param>', '></source>',
    );
    // This is not 100% reliable because it may output namespace declarations.
    // But otherwise it is extra-paranoid to work down to at least PHP 5.1
    $html = $e->ownerDocument->saveXML($e, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
    // in case any empty elements are expanded, collapse them again:
    $html = str_ireplace($selfclosingelements, '>', $html);
    return $html;
}
```

However, note that what you are doing is dangerous because it could potentially mix encodings. It is better to have your output as another DOMDocument and use `importNode()` to copy the nodes you want.  Alternatively, use an XSL stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just copy-pasted some example code and didn't bother trying to learn how it actually works...

Anyway, the `->nodeValue` part takes the element and returns the text content (because the element has a single text node child - if it had anything else, I don't know what `nodeValue` would give).

So, just remove the `->nodeValue` and you have your element.

Comment: Thats the thing i cant print it out. Says its not a string then

Comment: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in

Comment: You want the element, `DOMElement` is the element. It's not a string so I'm not sure what you expect it to print. Edit your question with example desired output so we don't have to guess what you are trying to say.

Comment: Well i am reading the following <img src="image url" /> right now i want to print that out to show the image so i read the img element and its url and if i echo it out it should show the image.

Comment: In that case, assuming you have PHP 5.3.6 or newer, use `$dom->saveHTML($items->item($i));` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php))