# Copying div from url with php

Tags: php

I found this code online to pull all  tags from a url

```
<?php
$url="http://www.foo.com/xxxxxx";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {

       echo '<img src="' . $tag->getAttribute('src') . '"></img>';
}
?>
```

and it works fine
now i am trying to adapt it to find specific  tags based on class.

```
<?php
$url="http://www.foo.com/xxxxxx";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByClassName('bar');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {

       echo '<div>' . $tag->getAttribute('div') . '</div>';
}
?>
```

but I keep getting this

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementsByClassName() in /index.php on line 9
```

what am i doing wrong

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` is Javascript, and not part of the DOMDocument class. You could use `getElementsByTagName()` and filter the result. Or see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728839/get-element-by-classname-with-domdocument-method

Answer (score 0):

### Please read the error messages!

The error message explicitly states you're calling an undefined method of an object. That alone could get you on track that something's wrong with that method.

The class synposis of DOMDocument is found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and can be used as a reference.

---

### The problem

You're calling the wrong method. You want to call `getElementByTagName()` (reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)), not `getElementByClassName()`, which is a method of `The HTML DOM Document Object` in JavaScript.