# php to extract data from a website

Tags: php

I want to get all `<p>` elements from 1st jokes so basically I made this script:

```
<?php
$url = "http://sms.hindijokes.co";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
@$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>".$html."
</body>      </html>");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query1 = "//h2[@class='entry-title']/a";
$query2 = "//div[@class='entry-content']/p";
$entries1 = $xpath->query($query1);
$entries2 = $xpath->query($query2);
$var1 = $entries1->item(0)->textContent;
$var2 = $entries2->item(0)->textContent;
echo "$var1"; 
echo "<br>";
$f = 5;
for($i = 0; $i < $f; $i++){
echo $entries2->item($i)->textContent."\n";
}
?>
```

This time I was knowing that there are five `<p>` elements in first joke but if I want it to be automate script, there would be sometimes more or less than five `<p>` elements so it would cause mess.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-classname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first `div`'s `p` elements only, so your query would be:

```
$entries2 = $xpath->query('//(div[@class='entry-content'])[1]/p');
```

Now you can iterate all `p` elements with `foreach()` loop (extracting its html contents):

```
$innerHtml = '';
foreach ($entries2 as $entry) {
    $children = $entry->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $innerHtml .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML($child);
    }
}
$innerHtml = str_replace(["\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"], '', $innerHtml);
```

Comment: How to get html content too.. like p elements is like this ( not using less than greater than)

Comment: how i get html content from p element included ? as their are <br> which needs to be included...

Comment: @AliveColdJuan Check my edited answer if it extracts inner html content. Its based on my old code and right now I'm not sure if it worked as I expect it should.

Answer (score 1):

`DOMXPath::query` returns `DOMNodeList` object. Use `DOMNodeList::length` property.

```
$f = $entries2->length;
```

Comment: How can i include br can you help me their are some <br> in p tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it is returning until null; but some joke has multiple **p** tags so its better for you to find it by your custom **[class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441697/call-to-undefined-method-domdocumentgetelementsbyclassname)/[id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728839/get-element-by-classname-with-domdocument-method)**

```
$i = 0;
while($entries2->item($i)->textContent!=NULL) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $i." ".$entries2->item($i)->textContent;
    $i++;
}
```