# Use PHP DOMdocument xpath to find element by class name and wrap in new tag

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I haven't used DOMdocument before so the syntax etc is all a bit new to me.

I'm trying to use PHP DOMdocument and Xpath to find and element by a specific class name and then wrap it in a new tag.

Eg: I have this inside a `<content:encoded> block`:

```
<iframe class="youtubeEmbed figureWrap" src="..."></iframe>
```

The class `figureWrap` means it needs wrapping in `<figure>` tags and `youtubeEmbed` means that figure requires a specific class adding to it (`op-interactive`)

I've found xpath query to detect things by class name but beyond that I'm getting a bit stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: `class` attributes are a little tricky, because they can contain several class names. I explained it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33446305/2265374

Comment: @ThW thanks I've got it to wrap now, but ideally I'd be good to remove (or change?) the parent <p> tag into the new wrapper element if that's feasible?

Comment: Changing node name, type or namespace is not possible. Create a new node, insert it before the one you want to replace, append all children to the new node and remove the old.

Comment: @ThW that's what I suspected I needed to do. I'm just having trouble getting the parent. Using the code in the main question, I've got that iframe but it's wrapped in <p> tags. I use xpath the find it and wrap in a <figure> tag, but still need to remove the parent paragraph wrapper. That's where I get stuck