# Get innerHTML from DOM in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, dom

I have a few divs

```
<div class="appname">Name 1</div>
<div class="appname">Name 2</div>
<div class="appname">Name 3</div>
```

I use DOM and `getElementsByClassName('appname')` to parse it using PHP. I want to print out all the names, but can't find anything that works. Already tried:

```
$linksname = $domname->getElementsByClassName('appname'); 
foreach ($linksname as $apptitle) {
echo $apptitle->nodeValue;
}
```

Nothing is working. Any help?

EDIT: just to clear up: the issue is not on how I am parsing the data using DOM. I purposely didn't include that part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441697/call-to-undefined-method-domdocumentgetelementsbyclassname/33446305#33446305

Comment: @JitendraMeena I don't think that is what I want

Comment: The method `DOMDocument::getElementsByClassName` doesn't exist. Use XPath instead.

Comment: Worked.  .......