# DOM How do I find links in class?

Tags: php, dom

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgw">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://somesites/index.html">
                <img src="http://somesites.com/picture.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
$div = $dom->getElementByClass('imgw'); 
$links = $div->getElementsByTagName('a'); 
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $li = $link->getAttribute('href');
    echo ($li."<br>");
}
```

I have been looking at this (`PHP DOMDocument`) but I still don't understand how to make it work.

Comment: Your last paragraph looks suspiciously like the one in  http://stackoverflow.com/q/20728839/1301076 I suggest you look at the answers there

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Try looking to see what `$div` and `$link` contain to help you understand.  You can use print_r() to print out objects or a debugger through various IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 is that you aren't using error reporting/checking error logs. Error reporting/logs would have told you:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementByClass()

So `getElementByClass` is not a function of DOMDocument. You could iterate through all `div`s, check if they have the class you are looking for, and then if so parse through those links.

```
$html = '<div class="imgw">
         <ul>
                        <li  >
                            <a href="http://somesites/index.html">
                                <img src="http://somesites.com/picture.jpg"/>
                            </a>


                        </li>
                    </ul>


            </div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div){
     if(preg_match('/\bimgw\b/', $div->getAttribute('class'))) {
         $links = $div->getElementsByTagName('a');
         foreach($links as $link){
              $li = $link->getAttribute('href');
              echo ($li."<br>");
         }
     }
}
```

Output:

```
http://somesites/index.html<br>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/460741