# How is it possible to get elements by class name in PHP (DOM selectors)?

Tags: php, class, dom

Apparently, in PHP, there are a few *DOM selectors* like `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName` but not the *class selector*, `getElementsByClassName` that is in **javaScript**, *but strangely, not in PHP.* Now, I have made a project that **has to use class selectors** in order to *locate the elements in that particular page's DOM,* but nethertheless, considering there's no `getElementsByClassName` method in PHP;
I can't complete my project correctly.

> So, how is it possible to apply "get elements by class name" in the
>   PHP Document Object Model(DOM)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you could use a `DOMXPath` query to target elements by tag and class quite easily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Element by ClassName with DOMdocument() Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728839/get-element-by-classname-with-domdocument-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) with a custom XPath query. See [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)

Comment: What's the use of answer which redirects to another answer?

Comment: @u_mulder The linked answer is about XPath in general, not how to use it with PHP's DOMDocument.