# Get content of a div in the current document with php

Tags: php, html

I want to get the content (only the number) of 'count-link' with php:

```
<div class="left">
<a class="count-link" href="http://url.com">
<span>22</span>
users
</a>
</div>
```

I have tried this, but it did not work:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$div = $doc->getElementByClass('count-link');
if($div) {
echo $div->textContent;
}
```

Comment: What is this magical `DOMDOcument::getElementByClass` method you talk about?

Comment: Seems that method `getElementByClass` not exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041073/how-to-get-a-child-of-php-domdocument-by-index

check this.

Comment: its there http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: Other Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728839/get-element-by-classname-with-domdocument-method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526069/php-domdocument-how-to-get-element

Comment: link does not help.. i need php.. @andyroo I still don't get it to work

Comment: anyone who can post a working solution for the exact code I provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work (tested):

```
<?php

function getTextBetweenTags($tag, $html, $strict=0)
{
    /*** a new dom object ***/
    $dom = new domDocument;

    /*** load the html into the object ***/
    if($strict==1)
    {
        $dom->loadXML($html);
    }
    else
    {
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
    }

    /*** discard white space ***/
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    /*** the tag by its tag name ***/
    $content = $dom->getElementsByTagname($tag);

    /*** the array to return ***/
    $out = array();
    foreach ($content as $item)
    {
        /*** add node value to the out array ***/
        $out[] = $item->nodeValue;
    }
    /*** return the results ***/
    return $out;
}

$html = '<div class="left">
<a class="count-link" href="http://url.com">
<span>22</span>
users
</a>
</div>';

//Example output array
print_r(getTextBetweenTags("span", $html));

//Example save in array
$myArr = getTextBetweenTags("span", $html);

//Example print text only
echo $myArr[0];

//Example save text only to var
$myText = $myArr[0];

?>
```

Comment: what do I have to insert for the tagname here? "span" ? And what do I insert for $html if i want the current file?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? The tag name is "span" obviously. But what do you mean with current file? Do you want to process html that hasn't been outputted yet? In that case, isn't it easier to use regex? Edit: If you scroll the code down, there's an example use.

Comment: Added examples to the code. Scroll it down and you should find everything you can possible need.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="left">
<a class="count-link" href="http://url.com">
<span id= "span_value">22</span>
users
</a>
</div>
```

and

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$div = $doc->getElementById('span_value');
if($div) {
echo $div->textContent;
}
```

I think this will work.

Comment: problem is, I do not want to change the code as is.. so i cannot add the id in the span

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp
check this

Comment: This is javascript in your link, OP needs PHP.